# Creating UNF for multiple actions

Tags: database-design, normalization

I am creating a database design for manufacture company for my coursework. The database design should be able to do these tasks:

1. Buy items from suppliers. (M - N)
2. Items are used for making products. Multiple items can be used to create multiple products. (M - N)
3. The products are sold to customers. Multiple order can have multiple products. (M - N)
4. A customer can have multiple orders. (1 - M)
5. A order can have multiple transaction. (1 - M)

So, with these business rules, I am not sure of how to create a un-normalized form.

My UNF (un-normalized form) looks like this.

```
ORDER 
(
    order_no, order_date, customer_no, customer_name, customer_phone, customer_address,
    {
        prod_no, 
        {
            item_no, item_desc, 
            {supplier_no, supplier_desc}
        }, 
        prod_desc, unit_price, ord_qty, line_total
    }, 
    order_total, 
    {trans_no, trans_amount, trans_status}
)
```

Should I create two UNF for two actions?

Order => to sell product to customers.
Item => to buy items from suppliers and create products.

Comment: What is your textbook/course material? What is their definition/characterization of "UNF"? Because there's no need to create a single "UNF" record. (You need only define a table for every application relationship in your list.) (Moreover your record is inadequate because a collection of such records cannot record suppliers who do not have outstanding orders.) So we need to know what your assignment expects a "UNF" design to be like.